# SKAction building a timer/score counter

Tags: ios, timer, sprite-kit

so I am trying to make a game with a timer and a score counter in the bottom right of the screen. but it is not appearing and I am not sure as to why

in - (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view

I have the code

```
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0f];
    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction performSelector:@selector(timer) onTarget:self], wait]];
    SKAction *repeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];
    [self runAction:repeat];
```

and timer looks like

```
-(void)timer
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    float multi = [defaults floatForKey:@"multi"];

    if(!_time)
    {
        _time=0;
    }
    else if(_time == 30)
    {
        multi = 1.5;
    }
    else if(_time == 60)
    {
        multi = 2;
    }
    else if(_time == 90)
    {
        multi = 2.5;
    }
    else if(_time == 120)
    {
        multi = 3.0;
    }
    else if(_time == 150)
    {
        multi = 3.5;
    }
    else if(_time == 180)
    {
        multi = 4.0;
    }
    else if(_time == 210)
    {
        multi = 4.5;
    }

    [defaults  setFloat:multi forKey:@"multi"];
    _time++;
    _score = multi * (float)_time;
    SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    myLabel.fontSize = 30;
    myLabel.position = CGPointMake(150,850);
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time %d Score %f",_time,_score];
}
```

_timer and _score are properties I have created for this scene

any help would be awesome thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the label to the node graph. For example:

```
[self addChild:myLabel];
```